# POST Request is working on Postman but getting 403 in JS

Tags: javascript, api, postman, http-status-code-403

I have tested an API `https://connect.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/contact/suspend-recording` with POST request in postman successfully and getting the 200 statuscode and it is working absolutely fine and suspend/pause the call recording according to the desired goals.
I generate the code by using POSTMAN Code Snippet and used it in my project/code and than when i test it, it throw 403 forbidden error. [image: POSTMAN] [image: Header] [image: 403 Error] In Inspection -> Network -> Response `{"message":"Signature expired: 20220324T135827Z is now earlier than 20220325T072547Z (20220325T073047Z - 5 min.)"}` [image: Response] In Inspection -> Network -> Headers [image]

```
function pauseRecording(){
//let contactId = contactId; //document.getElementById("contactId").value;

alert("ContactId Alert:" + contactId)
var settings = {
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://connect.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/contact/suspend-recording",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "X-Amz-Content-Sha256": "beaead3198f7da1e70d03ab969765e0821b24fc913697e929e726aeaebXXXXXX",
      "X-Amz-Date": "20220324T135827Z",
      "Authorization": "XXXX-XXXX-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXI7HVAVPV5LNWQN/20220324/us-east-1/connect/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=XXXXXXde1fc213ebf2191ebc518e01858fb6cc024773db9133deb7fbebc59XXX",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({
      "ContactId": contactId,
      "InitialContactId": contactId,
      "InstanceId": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }),
  };
  
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

HTML Button: `<button onclick="pauseRecording()">Pause Recording</button>`
Any Solution Please?

Comment: please add screen shot of headers tab in postman

Comment: Header Added...

Comment: i get some additional info on response header (for me:  InvalidSignatureException) please add some screan shot of network tab(in inspect) and response header

Comment: @foadabdollahi you are right, its SignatureException. Screenshots added..

Comment: i think your problem is not postman , it is sign generator.

Comment: so do i have to generate new AWS signature and used it?

Comment: yes, please read more : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html

Comment: i have generated and added the new AWS signature (Access & Secret Keys) but still the same error. `Signature expired: 20220324T135827Z is now earlier than 20220325T072547Z (20220325T073047Z - 5 min.)`

Comment: there is time/date related exception, should i change the time on my computer to us-east-1?

Comment: not need change you can convert it.

Comment: How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First give us response body, I assume you getting CORS error. You calling this api from browser, so it means request goes from client side (from browser). So your response error telling you about CORS error. It means you have to configure CORS in your API disabling your CORS origin ...

[Related document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors)

Comment: i think you are wrong! CORS error is not 403 error. CORS is browser error and not a defined http status code!